# How to modify regex to match only needed strings but not others

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have this regex currently

```
/(?<=^|\/)(?:(?!\/)(?!.*\/))(.*?)[:-]v([\d.-]+)(?=\.|$)/
```

It should result in the captured group from these strings:

```
rhmtc/openshift-velero-plugin-rhel8:v1.7.9-4
oc-mirror-plugin-container-v4.13.0-202305091542.p0.gbee629a.assembly.stream
openshift4/ose-cluster-ingress-operator:v4.7.0-202208021424.p0.ge76561d.assembly.stream
container-native-virtualization/hco-bundle-registry-rhel9:v4.13.0.rhel9-2172
```

It should get me the name and the version separately like:

name: `openshift-velero-plugin-rhel8`, version: `1.7.9-4`

or:

name: `oc-mirror-plugin-container`, version: `4.13.0`

I needed to add the possibility of this string to be matched by the regex:

```
oadp/oadp-velero-plugin-for-aws-rhel8:1.0.4-5
```

So I thought of changing the regex to

```
/(?<=^|\/)(?:(?!\/)(?!.*\/))(.*?)[:-]v?([\d.-]+)(?=\.|$)/
```

But now these strings gets matched:

```
openssl-1:1.1.1k-9.el8_7
java-1.8.0-ibm-1:1.8.0.7.15-1jpp.1.el7
```

And I don't want that.

Changing the capture groups didn't work as well as excluding everything that matched `-\d:`

What can I try next?

Comment: You have to encode some other constraints in your expression. For example `(?<=^|\/)(?!\/)(?!.*\/)(.*?)[:-]v?((?<=v)[\d.-]+|[\d.-]+(?=$))(?=\.|$)` encodes the fact that, if the numerical part is not preceded by `v`, then it must be followed by the end of the string.

Comment: I apologize in advance as this likely NOT the answer you want to hear, if it were me I would do everything in my power to regularized the input so that its format was more uniform in terms of delimiters etc. Is this something that you have considered or are your hands complete tied on the format of the input file/data?

Comment: Assuming semantic versioning: [`(?<=^|\/)(?!.*\/)(.*?)[:-]v?(\d+(?:\.\d+){2}(?:-\d+)?)(?=\.(?!\d)|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/SLEUIa/1)

Comment: *"And I dont want that."*: can you express in words what it is in those strings that makes clear they shouldn't match?

Answer (score 0):

As you want 2 capture groups, you can write this lookbehind `(?<=^|\/)` just as a non capture group `(?:^|\/)`

Then you can exclude the 2 matches from your question by asserting that after the match there is either a dot followed by word character except for a digit, or the end of the string

```
(?:^|\/)([^\s/]+)[:-]v?(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)(?:-\d+)?(?=\.[^\W\d]|$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:^|\/)` Either assert the start of the string or match `/`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s/]+` Match 1+ chars other than `/` or a whitespace char
- `)` Close group 1
- `[:-]v?` Match either `:` or `-` followed by an optional `v`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)+` Match 1+ digits, repeat 1+ times a `.` and 1+ digits
- `)` Close group 2
- `(?:-\d+)?` Match an optional part with `-` and 1+ digits
- `(?=\.[^\W\d]|$)` Positive lookahead, assert either `.` followed by a word char except for a digit, or assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fnHqeu/1)